# How do I correctly include and test an ActiveSupport::Concern in an RSpec mocked_model?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec, mocking

I'm trying to spec a module by including it in a basic mock_model object. However, when I call the instance method defined in the module ActiveRecord tries to establish a connection with the database.

The module:

```
module Stuff
    module SoftDelete
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        def soft_delete
            puts "Called here"
        end
    end
end
```

The Spec:

```
describe Stuff::SoftDelete do
    class Network < ActiveRecord::Base
        include Stuff::SoftDelete
        attr_accessor :deleted_at
    end

    before (:each) do
        @network = mock_model(Network)
    end

    context "When a record is deleted" do
        it "is marked as deleted" do
            @network.soft_delete
        end
    end
end
```

When I run this Spec, the following error occurs:

```
  1) Stuff::SoftDelete When a record is deleted is marked as deleted
     Failure/Error: @network.soft_delete
     ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished:
       ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
     # ./spec/apoc/soft_delete_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**Note**: If I include the SoftDelete module in a real ActiveRecord class, it will work. It just seems that mock_model isn't able to deal with the module.

Would love some help on this one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you trust ActiveRecord?  If so, don't inherit from it; test your module in isolation.  If your module includes calls ActiveRecord methods, stub them and test only your code.